# rotate square with rotateAnimation

Tags: java, android

I have a LinearLayout with an ImageView with a square image in the center which I need to apply rotation.  Bordering the ImageView on each of its 4 sides is a frame constructed from 4 other views.  If I rotate the ImageView 45degrees, does the ImageView get clipped by the other views?  How does rotateAnimation respect the boundaries of the ImageView?

Comment: Why not just try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;


public class ImageFunctionsActivity extends Activity
```

{

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ImageView iv;
float degree=0;
GestureDetector gd;
Context context;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageTeddy);
    context=getApplicationContext();

    rotate(degree);


}

void rotate(float x)
{
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.tedd);

    int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();

    int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();


    int newWidth = 200;

    int newHeight  = 200;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f

     float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

     float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

     matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
     matrix.postRotate(x);

     Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,width, height, matrix, true);

     iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
     iv.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP)
    {
        degree=degree+10;
        rotate(degree);
    }
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) // rotate anti-clockwise
    {
            degree=degree-10;
            rotate(degree);
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will answer your question :

> Note: Regardless of how your animation may move or resize, the bounds of the View that holds your animation will not automatically adjust to accommodate it. Even so, the animation will still be drawn beyond the bounds of its View and will not be clipped. However, clipping will occur if the animation exceeds the bounds of the parent View.

([Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html))